# Search results with pagination

Tags: mysql, search, pagination

A search result with pagination:
I have created this for my database search results with pagination

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("server","some_user","password"); // Enter hostname,user,password 
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  // select database
  mysql_select_db("some_db", $con);
$output = '';




//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    //pagination code

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE Title Like '%$searchq%'"); //Counting total number of rows in the table 'data',
  $total_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
  // setup configuration//  
//step:3

  $base_url = 'http://localhost/php_search/New/index.php';    //Provide location of you index file  
  $per_page = 1;                           //number of results to shown per page 
  $num_links = 8;                           // how many links you want to show
  $total_rows = $total_rows; 
  $cur_page = 1;                           // set default current page to 1
  //now we will extract information from url//
//step:4
    if(isset($_GET['search']))
    {
      $cur_page = $_GET['search'];
      $cur_page = ($cur_page < 1)? 1 : $cur_page;            //if page no. in url is less then 1 or -ve
    }
    // calculate limit and offset, it'll will be used for Sql Query//
//step:5
    $offset = ($cur_page-1)*$per_page;                //setting offset

    $pages = ceil($total_rows/$per_page);              // no of page to be created
    //Calculate the start and end page numbers for pagination links//
//step:6

    $start = (($cur_page - $num_links) > 0) ? ($cur_page - ($num_links - 1)) : 1;
    $end   = (($cur_page + $num_links) < $pages) ? ($cur_page + $num_links) : $pages;
    //query the database with calculated OFFSET //
//step:7
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE Title Like '%$searchq%' LIMIT ".$per_page." OFFSET ".$offset);

 mysql_close($con);

//pagination code
if(isset($res))
{

        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
        {
            $title = $result['Title'];
            $name = $result['name'];
            $description = $result['Description'];

            $output .='<div><h1><a href="http://server.com/soome_page.php?name='.$name.'">'.$title.'</a><br>'.$name.'</h1><br>'.$description.'</div>';


    }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search here" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
<?php print("$output"); ?>



<div id="pagination">
        <div id="pagiCount">
            <?php
                if(isset($pages))
                {  
                    if($pages > 1)        
                    {    if($cur_page > $num_links)     // for taking to page 1 //
                        {   $dir = "first";
                            echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search='.(1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                        }
                       if($cur_page > 1) 
                        {
                            $dir = "prev";
                            echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search='.($cur_page-1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                        }                 

                        for($x=$start ; $x<=$end ;$x++)
                        {

                            echo ($x == $cur_page) ? '<strong>'.$x.'</strong> ':'<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
                        }
                        if($cur_page < $pages )
                        {   $dir = "next";
                            echo '<span id="next"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search='.($cur_page+1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                        }
                        if($cur_page < ($pages-$num_links) )
                        {   $dir = "last";

                            echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search='.$pages.'">'.$dir.'</a> '; 
                        }   
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have posted this code with which i am not getting any result on choosing another page
The pagination do occurs but on clicking to the second page there is no search result
Any help please

Comment: Obligatory MySQL is deprecated and SQL Injection comment.

Answer (score 0):

you pass the page number as "search" parameter

```
?search='.($cur_page+1)
```

but collect data only when $_POST['search'] is set

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
```

so when you click a page link, you only have $_GET['search'] set, not $_POST['search']